# Problem with \multicolumn in \longtabu environment

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I'm a relative newbie to LaTeX and am having a problem with a `longtabu` table. I've set it up with alternating row colors, which works great. However, this makes the captions on all but the first page the alternate color. To get around this I tried a `\multicolumn` row in the header as shown in the MWE below. I also included a `\multicolumn` row in the footer with the same results.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabu,xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[colorlinks = true,
            linkcolor = blue,
            urlcolor  = blue,
            citecolor = blue,
            anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref}            
\usepackage{longtable}


\begin{document}

\taburowcolors[2]{white .. blue!20}

\tabulinesep=6pt
\arrayrulewidth=1pt 

\begin{longtabu}[h]{| m{1.75in} | m{1.5in} | m{2.75in} |}


\caption{This is the first page header} \label{Table:example}\\
 \rowcolor{blue}\color{white}Column 1  & \color{white}Column 2 & \color{white}Column 3\\
\endfirsthead

\rowcolor{white}\multicolumn{3}{c}{Table~\ref{Table:example}: Continued from previous page}\\
%\caption{Continued from previous page}\\
 \rowcolor{blue}\color{white}Column 1  & \color{white}Column 2 & \color{white}Column 3\\ 
\endhead

\hline
%\rowcolor{white} \multicolumn{3}{l}{Continued on next page}\\ 

\endfoot

\hline
\endlastfoot


This is Column 1 & This column describes Column 1 and is generally a little longer &  This is a longer description that will take up a few lines of text in the table. It is really just a bunch of text. This really means nothing in this minimum working example other than to take up space in the table.\\

This is Column 1 & This column describes Column 1 and is generally a little longer &  This is a longer description that will take up a few lines of text in the table. It is really just a bunch of text. This really means nothing in this minimum working example other than to take up space in the table.\\

This is Column 1 & This column describes Column 1 and is generally a little longer &  This is a longer description that will take up a few lines of text in the table. It is really just a bunch of text. This really means nothing in this minimum working example other than to take up space in the table.\\

This is Column 1 & This column describes Column 1 and is generally a little longer &  This is a longer description that will take up a few lines of text in the table. It is really just a bunch of text. This really means nothing in this minimum working example other than to take up space in the table.\\

This is Column 1 & This column describes Column 1 and is generally a little longer &  This is a longer description that will take up a few lines of text in the table. It is really just a bunch of text. This really means nothing in this minimum working example other than to take up space in the table.\\

This is Column 1 & This column describes Column 1 and is generally a little longer &  This is a longer description that will take up a few lines of text in the table. It is really just a bunch of text. This really means nothing in this minimum working example other than to take up space in the table.\\

This is Column 1 & This column describes Column 1 and is generally a little longer &  This is a longer description that will take up a few lines of text in the table. It is really just a bunch of text. This really means nothing in this minimum working example other than to take up space in the table.\\

This is Column 1 & This column describes Column 1 and is generally a little longer &  This is a longer description that will take up a few lines of text in the table. It is really just a bunch of text. This really means nothing in this minimum working example other than to take up space in the table.\\

This is Column 1 & This column describes Column 1 and is generally a little longer &  This is a longer description that will take up a few lines of text in the table. It is really just a bunch of text. This really means nothing in this minimum working example other than to take up space in the table.\\

This is Column 1 & This column describes Column 1 and is generally a little longer &  This is a longer description that will take up a few lines of text in the table. It is really just a bunch of text. This really means nothing in this minimum working example other than to take up space in the table.\\

This is Column 1 & This column describes Column 1 and is generally a little longer &  This is a longer description that will take up a few lines of text in the table. It is really just a bunch of text. This really means nothing in this minimum working example other than to take up space in the table.\\


\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

This works but throws a couple of 
`Misplaced\omit \end{longtabu}`

errors and a bunch of overfull and underfull `\hbox` as shown below.

```
line 66: Misplaced \omit \end{longtabu}
line 66: Misplaced \omit \end{longtabu}
line 66: Overfull \hbox (43.61536pt too wide) in alignment
line 66: Overfull \hbox (43.61536pt too wide) in alignment
line 66: Overfull \hbox (43.61536pt too wide) in alignment
line 66: Overfull \hbox (43.61536pt too wide) in alignment
line 66: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
line 66: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
line 66: Underfull \hbox (badness 2837) in paragraph
line 66: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
line 66: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
line 66: Underfull \hbox (badness 2837) in paragraph
line 66: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
line 66: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
line 66: Underfull \hbox (badness 2837) in paragraph
line 66: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
line 66: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
line 66: Underfull \hbox (badness 2837) in paragraph
line 66: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
line 66: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
line 66: Underfull \hbox (badness 2837) in paragraph
line 66: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
line 66: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
line 66: Underfull \hbox (badness 2837) in paragraph
line 66: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
line 66: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
line 66: Underfull \hbox (badness 2837) in paragraph
line 66: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
line 66: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
line 66: Underfull \hbox (badness 2837) in paragraph
line 66: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
line 66: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
line 66: Underfull \hbox (badness 2837) in paragraph
line 66: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
line 66: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
line 66: Underfull \hbox (badness 2837) in paragraph
line 66: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
line 66: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
line 66: Underfull \hbox (badness 2837) in paragraph
line 66: Overfull \hbox (43.61536pt too wide) in alignment
```

Is there something that I can do to get rid of the errors?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\cellcolor`, not `\rowcolor`:

```
\begin{longtabu}{| >{\raggedright}m{1.75in} | >{\raggedright}m{1.5in} | >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{2.75i$


\caption{This is the first page header} \label{Table:example}\\
 \rowcolor{blue}\color{white}Column 1  & \color{white}Column 2 & \color{white}Column 3\\
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{3}{c}{\cellcolor{white}Table~\ref{Table:example}: Continued from previous page}\\[\bigskipamount]
 \rowcolor{blue}\color{white}Column 1  & \color{white}Column 2 & \color{white}Column 3\\
\endhead
```

I set a small margin just to avoid the table overshooting the width. With `\raggedright` the cells don't throw tens of `Underfull \hbox` warnings.

[image]

Comment: @John It is great that the answer works great, so please remember upvoting the answer in addition to accepting it.